# Copiar un estilo en SCSS

Tags: css3, scss

Tengo una pregunta que no sé si esa obvia, pero me interesaría bastante

Según conozco de CSS se  puede copiar un estilo del tipo el hover de a y la clase .activated, por lo que tendrán los mismos estilos

```
header a:hover, .activated {
    background: green;
}
```

¿Cómo se podría hacer con SCSS?

Lo pregunto porque sé que el hover y heredar en general es algo asi en css

```
header a {
    background: black;

    &:hover{
        background: yellow;
    }
}
```

pero quisiera saber si se puede hacer algo parecido o si tengo que repetir el código

Y bueno, en este caso .activated también será un a, no sé si eso ayude

// Modificación

Bueno, el código completo que tengo sobre eso sería básicamente esto

```
header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: rgba($color: #611081, $alpha: 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  ul {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: inherit;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 90px;

    margin: 0px auto {
      top: -4px;
    }

    a {
      display: block;
      padding: 0px 20px;
      height: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      transition: all 300ms;

      &:hover {
        background: rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: 0.8);
      }
    }

    .actived {
      background: rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: 0.8);
    }
  }
}
```

Al final opté por simplemente repetir el código, no sé si haya forma de no hacerlo

Comment: Insisto, la pseudo-clase es 'active', no actived, con eso lo que estás haciendo es crear una clase. La tendrías que declarar como te indicaba abajo. Por favor indica si mi respuesta te ha sido de ayuda o no, porque no tengo claro si he aclarado tu duda.

Comment: @JorgeGuz es que estoy usando Angular y estoy  usando esta madre [routerLinkActive]="['actived']" que me pone una clase si el router es el activado

Comment: Si no quieres repetir propiedades en varios selectores en el scss puedes usar un mixin

Comment: También tienes la opción de cambiar de tipo de selector en a, usa uno de clase y usa & para prefijar .activated y asi lo tendrías en ambos

Comment: Muchas gracias @ElliotWilliamson :o no sabía lo que era un mixin, lo acabo de investigar y está mucho mejor de lo que buscaba XD y también hice lo segundo

Answer (score 0):

En este caso sí vas a tener que "duplicar" el código, luego al compilar sí que se te creará una clase del tipo que planteas en el archivo 'css'. La 'pseudoclase' es 'active'. Tu código 'scss' debería ser algo así en este caso:

```
 header a {
      background: black;

      &:hover{
          background: yellow;
      }
      &:active{
         background: yellow;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Me equivoqué y no había colocado el a

Comment: el asunto es que serían header a{} y uno de los a sería el activo, es un menú

Comment: Es un ejemplo, el que tengo yo, es un poquito mas grande porque tiene los li y mas madres, lo simplifiqué

Comment: Me imagino que no es todo tu código, el caso es que en scss se tiene que declarar las pseudo-clases de ese modo, es más laborioso pero puedes pasármelo con variables o clases extendidas.

Comment: Ya lo he añadido